# Why is Meteor.call() not recognized?

Tags: javascript, rest, meteor, http-get

This question has morphed enough from its [ancestor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33283706/why-is-alert-defined-and-then-two-lines-later-its-not-meteor) that it was suggested I post a new question.

When I call my "*insertPerson*" method, which then calls my "*getTextAddrAsEmailAddr*" method, I see, in the console, my two debug console.log msgs:

```
I20151022-07:59:07.240(-7)? insertPerson reached
I20151022-07:59:07.365(-7)? phone is 0871632810
```

...followed by this exception:

```
I20151022-07:59:07.365(-7)? Exception while invoking method 'insertPerson' TypeE
rror: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined
I20151022-07:59:07.365(-7)?     at [object Object].Meteor.methods.getTextAddrAsE
mailAddr (both/methods.js:37:28)
```

NOTE: Line 37 in methods.js is:

```
return Meteor.http.call("GET", restcall);
```

For context, the entire methods.js file is:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'insertPerson': function(firstname, lastname, streetaddr1, streetaddr2, placename, stateorprov, zipcode, emailaddr, phone, notes) {
        console.log('insertPerson reached'); // TODO: Remove before deploying
        check(firstname, String);
        . . .
        console.log('phone is ' + phone);
        var textAddrAsEmailAddr = Meteor.call('getTextAddrAsEmailAddr', phone);
        console.log('textAddrAsEmailAddr is ' + textAddrAsEmailAddr);

        People.insert({
            per_firstname: firstname,
            per_lastname: lastname,
            per_streetaddr1: streetaddr1,
            per_streetaddr2: streetaddr2,
            per_placename: placename,
            per_stateorprov: stateorprov,
            per_zipcode: zipcode,
            per_emailaddr: emailaddr,
            per_phone: phone,
            per_textaddrasemailaddr: phone,
            per_notes: notes,
            per_createdBy: this.userId
        });
    },
    'getTextAddrAsEmailAddr': function(phone) {
        this.unblock();
        var restcall = 'http://www.reminder.com/phone.check.php?number=' + phone;
        return Meteor.http.call("GET", restcall);
    }
});
```

Is something wrong with my Meteor.http.call() call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `HTTP.call()` not `Meteor.http.call()` according to the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http).

(Also make sure you've added the package with `meteor add http`).

Comment: Yep, I needed to do both those things (remove the superfluous ".http" and add the http package.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it is not written as a hard fact inside the docs but I am pretty sure, that `Meteor.call()` is expected to make a remote call from client to server.

In addition, I am wondering, why you would make a `Meteor.call()` at this point, when you are already "on server side".

Try:

```
function getTextAddrAsEmailAddr(scope, phone) {
    scope.unblock();
    var restcall = 'http://www.reminder.com/phone.check.php?number=' + phone;
    return HTTP.get(restcall);
}

Meteor.methods({
  'insertPerson': function(firstname, lastname, streetaddr1, streetaddr2, placename, stateorprov, zipcode, emailaddr, phone, notes) {
     console.log('insertPerson reached'); // TODO: Remove before deploying
     check(firstname, String);
     . . .
     console.log('phone is ' + phone);
     var textAddrAsEmailAddr = getTextAddrAsEmailAddr(this, phone);
     console.log('textAddrAsEmailAddr is ' + textAddrAsEmailAddr);

     People.insert({
        per_firstname: firstname,
        per_lastname: lastname,
        per_streetaddr1: streetaddr1,
        per_streetaddr2: streetaddr2,
        per_placename: placename,
        per_stateorprov: stateorprov,
        per_zipcode: zipcode,
        per_emailaddr: emailaddr,
        per_phone: phone,
        per_textaddrasemailaddr: phone,
        per_notes: notes,
        per_createdBy: this.userId
    });

    return true;
  }
});
```

If you want to have the function `getTextAddrAsEmailAddr` available as a Meteor method as well, just add:

```
'getTextAddrAsEmailAddr': function(phone) {
    return getTextAddrAsEmailAddr(this, phone);
}
```

Hope that fixes it for you

Cheers
Tom

---

Update:

I was wondering myself about the overhead and correctness about using `Meteor.call()`

1. You may use it everywhere and anywhere
2. Be aware of the overhead

`Meteor.call` is defined in:

[Package ddp-client/livedata_connection.js L665](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/ddp-client/livedata_connection.js#L665)

and will run via `Meteor.apply` all the time which is defined at:

[Package ddp-client/livedata_connection.js L706](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/ddp-client/livedata_connection.js#L706)

If you check that source from [L707-L912](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/ddp-client/livedata_connection.js#L707-L912), I guess it is not wondering, that the suggestion to call the function directly is much more efficient.

Comment: What is the purpose of "return true" in the insertPerson() method?

Comment: I tried that, and got: "Exception while simulating the effect of invoking 'insertPerson' Error: Can't make a blocking HTTP call from the client; callback required.(…) Error: Can't make a blocking HTTP call from the client; callback required."

Comment: I made a MeteorPad for you that should give you the right move: http://meteorpad.com/pad/5hRPaC8y4BsRo6Ttf/MeteorCallSample